# How can I avoid Run as Administrator every time in windows machine

Tags: windows, windows-7

For editing the JSP files in the c: I have to run notepad and command prompt `Run as Administrator` every time. I am using windows 7 and only one user in the system. Can't I login to the system as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this will help:

```
To mark an application to always run as an administrator, do the following:

1. On the Start menu, locate the program that you want to always run as an administrator.
2. Right-click the application’s shortcut, and then click Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog box, click the Compatibility tab.
4. Do one of the following:

    To apply the setting to the currently logged-on user, 
        select the Run This Program As An Administrator check box, and then click OK.
    To apply the setting to all users on the computer and 
        regardless of which shortcut is used to start the application, 
        click Change Setting For All Users to display the Properties dialog box for the application’s .exe file, 
        select the Run This Program As An Administrator check box, and then click OK twice.
```

**Update**

You have to first open `C:\windows\explorer.exe` as `Administrator`. Then browse to this location: `C:\Windows\System32\`. Then right click `Notepad.exe` and change properties. Do the same for `command prompt` at location `C:\WINDOWS\system32\'.

Comment: Yes it is working for the installed applications, But it is not working for command prompt. All the options(compatibility mode, Settings, Privilege Level) are inactive.

Comment: Updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you placed the .jsp files in a location where standard user accounts don't have write access by default. This includes the root of the C: drive... standard user accounts no longer have write access to the root C:\ folder. This has been true since Windows 2000 and Windows XP.

People have gotten away with it for a long time since then because so many run as an administrator account all the time, and so were able to write files to the C:\ folder anyway. Starting with Windows Vista, you no longer have administrator rights by default... even when logged in as the administrator account. Instead, to use your Administrator privileges you must use the "Run as Administrator" option on the context menu.

To get around your file editing problem, you can change the security permissions on specific folders where your *.jsp files live to allow your specific user account to have write access to that folder. You probably should not do this to the entire C: drive. Instead, move the jsp files to a folder you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run everything as admin by logging on as admin, and turning off UAC.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is NTFS Security.

Your rights as a normal user don't allow you to create files on the root of the drive, therefore you always need administrator right to do so.

To disable such behaviour you need to open the security properties dialog with advanced options on the drive you wish to update the security tokens on:

[image]

After that update the permissions accordingly to allow full access on the root of the C drive:

[image]

Enable the permissions you want, make sure to apply it **only** to the root drive FOLDER (else important windows files could be accessed/modified by normal users)

[image]

Okay, apply and you are ready to rock'n'roll.

If you still need administrator acces, you need to set the INTEGRITY LEVEL of the process to medium or low, when a file has high integrity level only adinistrators can access and modify the files.

To change the integrity level use the ICACLS tool on the file (included in windows). Make sure to execute the tool from an elevated command prompt.

[image]